# Don't auto-flag rollback wars involving one user

Tags: feature-request, community-user, rollbacks

Today, [this](https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/posts/5293/revisions) was flagged as a rollback war by Community ♦.

[image]

I ... don't think it counts as a rollback war when a non split-personality user rollbacks and then rollbacks the rollback.

Could rollbacks of a rollback by the same user not count towards the rollback war flag? To me, this seems like a pretty common use case, I've accidentally rollbacked things myself.

Comment: I like that you can [punch a user](http://stackapps.com/questions/3802/punch-a-user-button) in the revision history. People who rollback their rollbacks should get a punch.

Comment: @Antony: I really ought to modify my screenshot extension to remove all punch buttons :P\

Comment: @Manishearth: I think you should hack your usercard to provide a "punch all involved" link. Would be very satisfying.

Comment: @Mat: http://i.stack.imgur.com/KMQnH.png